# Error while calling google+ method plusService.People.Get

Tags: google-api, google-plus

The Google+ API is set to "On" from google's developer console. I am fetching the profile information of the user by supplying the api key but I get an error saying:

Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project. [403]

```
  BaseClientService.Initializer ini = new BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = "" };
  PlusService plusService = new PlusService(ini);
  if (plusService != null)
  {
         PeopleResource.GetRequest prgr = plusService.People.Get("me");
         Person googleUser = prgr.Execute();
  }
```

The error is thrown when Execute is called.

Does this service needs to be set up with "billed" profile ? This may be the reason I am getting access error.

Answer (score 0):

The "me" argument only works when you have an authenticated user's OAuth 2.0 access token. Simple API access with a key only allows access to public data - try putting in a numeric user id instead of me and you should get a response.